Double borders are not set
Until recently my script was putting a double border as it should, but about 3 days ago it started putting a single thin border as if I had specified “SOLID” instead of “DOUBLE”. How can I fix it?
You probably don't need the code, but I'll attach it:
function Newboards() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var startRow = range.getRow();
  var endRow = range.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = range.getLastColumn();
  var data = range.getValues();

  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var valueInColumnE = data[i][6];
    var valueInColumnEPrevious = data[i-1][6];
    if (valueInColumnE !== valueInColumnEPrevious) {
      var rowIndex = startRow + i;
      var rowRange = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 7, 1, lastColumn - 6);
      // PROBLEM HERE
      rowRange.setBorder(true, null, null, null, null, null, "blaсk", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DOUBLE);
    }
  }
  var lastRowRange = sheet.getRange(endRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
  lastRowRange.setBorder(null, null, true, null, null, null, "black", SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID_THICK);
}

All other border styles are set correctly, including SOLID.

It probably is a bug from Google, I have the same issue...
The worst being it doesn't follow their own docs : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/border-style?hl=fr
